# C++ memory allocation use Under Green Hills INTEGRITY

Tags: c++, heap-memory, rtos, greenhills

Sorry I'm new to Greenhill's. I'm using MULTI 6.1.6 and my language of choice is C++.

I have a problem when try to use simulator to initiate an object of a class bigger than 1M in size using new.

```
Class_Big* big_obj;
Class_Big = new Class_Big();
Class_Small* Small_obj;
Small_obj = new Class_Small();
```

if sizeOf(Class_Big) > 1MB it simply never call the class constructor, return NULL and go to the next instruction (Class_Small* Small_obj;) and creates the next object correctly. If I scope out some variables on the Class_Big to make its size < 1MB the code works fine and the object created.

I added both

```
MemoryPoolSize="0x200000"
HeapSize="0x200000"
```

to my xml file.

Another error I get in building phase If I used a lib have a big class:

```
intex: error: Not enough RAM for request.
intex: fatal: Integrate failed.
Error: build failed
```

Can you help with it?

Thanks

Comment: _"I have a problem"_ is not a problem description. What problem? What bad thing happens? Do you get an error that you can quote in your post?

Comment: First thanks for reply. Actually no I don't get any error. the class constructor does not even get called it simply return NULL and go to the next command.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include that info and anything else that would help fully describe your problem

Comment: Surely your GH licence includes technical support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To specify memory sizes for the Heap and memory pool, in the MULTI GUI go to the .int file (it can be found under the .gpj dropdown when it is expanded) and double click on it to edit it. Then right-click inside the purple box and go to "Edit". Go to the "Attributes" tab and you can modify the memory pool size and heap size to be larger.

Alternatively you can just edit the .int file in a text editor, but if you want to use the gui to set these follow the above steps.

Also from their manual:

> "Check the .bsp file in use. The memory declared with the
>   MinimumAddress/MaximumAddress keywords must match your board's memory.
>   If it does not, modify these keywords as needed. If the memory
>   declared in the .bsp file does match the board, you must modify your
>   application to use less memory."

Additionally, check the default.ld and you can set the values for the RAM limits there. Look at __INTEGRITY_RamLimit and the other values there. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

With INTEGRITY you are in total control of how much memory is used for each partition. It is a static configuration. Everything, code stack heap you name it, comes out of that. So if you have a bunch of code, automatics, etc in the partition then a memory allocation may fail if you ask for too much. Try increasing the size.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of the problem Basically I should have modified the "VirtualHeapSize" on the .ld component file.

Second part still try to figure it out.